# I want read a file but ignore repeating lines. How to do that?

Tags: perl

I am reading a text file from perl which is as follows:

```
    USA 1266222 John
    Russia 2212222 Jenny
    USA 1266222 John
    China 213111 Chian
```

I want to ignore repeating lines. How should i do that? In this case USA should just be shown once.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  If the below solution answers your question, please take the time to give it the green check mark.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -ane '$s{$F[0]}++ or print' file
```

Comment: You would need to `sort` before `uniq`, or `sort -u` which may not be desirable.